# sIFR 3 showing on my Home Pge but not on any other pages

Tags: javascript, flash, wordpress, sifr3

I have integrated sIFR3 and it shows perfectly in my [home page](http://test.idghosting.ca/drbali/) but not on any other pages. I never changed anything only the name of the font.

Here is my sifr-config.js:

```
 sIFR.replace(helvetica, {
  selector: 'h3', wmode:"transparent",
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #ffffff; font-size:18px; margin:0; padding:0;}'
});
sIFR.replace(helvetica, {
  selector: 'h2', wmode:"transparent",
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #5b2e13; font-size:31px; margin:0; padding:0;}'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it in my sifr-config.js I have this line

```
var helvetica = { src: 'wp-content/themes/default/sifr3/helveticathin.swf' };
```

So it works perfectly in the Home Page because it still the right path but as soon as I move into another page it won't show anymore because the URL path to the font.swf is incorrent so I just had to put in the absolute URL for it.